# How to get all other postcodes or (latitude & longitude) from table near by given postcode and given radius in miles in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table with latitude,longitude and postcodes. I want select the records which are near by given postcode and radius in miles. e.g user will give inputs postcode = 'NW44JL' and radius = 1 mile. I need to get all the records from the table with in 1 mile radius of postcode 'NW44JL'. Can anyone help me to get this. Thanks

Comment: What does Google Maps have to do with this?

Comment: I've removed google maps tag now. Thanks lc

Comment: In what coordinate system are your coordinates? What you want is relatively easy, but first you must be able to transform the coordinates to meter/mile based coordinate system.

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @radius int
--Radius for circle
set @radius=1

select distinct tb1.postcodes from table1 tb1
join table1 tb2 on (Power((tb1.latitude - tb2.latitude),2) + POWER((tb1.longitude - tb2.longitude),2)) < POWER(@radius,2)
where tb2.postcodes='NW44JL'
```

table1 is your table name

consided latitude and longitude in miles.
If not need to convert to miles

Answer (score 1):

For this you'll want to use the built in `SPATIAL` datatypes:

[MSDN (Designing and Implementing Spatial Storage (Database Engine))](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933790%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Try the following tutorials to get you started, written by the user @SQLMenace:

[SQL Server Zipcode Latitude/Longitude proximity distance search](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-zipcode-latitude-longitude-pr/)

and

[SQL Server 2008 Proximity Search With The Geography Data Type](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-2008-proximity-search-with-th/)