# SQL query that gets all the zip codes (address) within a 20-mile radius of a given zip code

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My query matches only the zip codes that equal each other. I need a query that can return all the zip codes that are in a radius of 20 miles to a given zip code.

```
DECLARE @cZip VARCHAR(5)
SET @cZip = '63026'
DECLARE @dMin DECIMAL = 20 * 32186.9 -- metres

DECLARE @c GEOGRAPHY
SELECT @c = GEOGRAPHY::Parse('Point(' + CAST(longitude AS VARCHAR)+ ' '     + CAST(latitude AS VARCHAR) + ')')
FROM wcr_sales_zip_info.dbo.utT_ZIP_Long_Lat
WHERE ZIP_CD = @cZip

SELECT  S.ZIP_CD
    ,AAE.AGN_FIRST_NM
    ,AAE.AGN_LAST_NM
    ,AAE.AGN_ADDRESS_CD
    ,AAE.AGN_CITY_CD
    ,AAE.AGN_STATE_CD
    ,AAE.AGN_ZIP_CD
    ,AAE.AGN_AGENT_NBR
    ,AAE.AGN_EMAIL_NBR
    ,AC.CANDIDATE_ID
    ,AC.FIRST_NM
    ,AC.LAST_NM
    ,AC.ADDRESS_TXT
    ,AC.CITY
    ,AC.STATE_CD
    ,AC.ZIP AS 'ZIP1'                   
    ,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(AC.HOME_PHONE_NBR,1,0,'  ('),6,0,') '),11,0,'-') AS 'HOME_PHONE_NBR' 
    ,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(AC.ALT_PHONE_NBR,1,0,' ('),6,0,') '),11,0,'-') AS 'ALT_PHONE_NBR'
    ,AC.EMAIL
    ,AC.PREF_CONTACT_METHOD_CD
    ,AC.TRAVEL_TIME_MINS_NBR
    ,AC.TRAVEL_DISTANCE_MLS_NBR
    ,AC.ADDED_DT    
FROM wcr_sales_zip_info.dbo.utT_ZIP_Long_Lat S
JOIN ASRD_AGENT_AUTO_EMAIL AAE ON S.ZIP_CD = AAE.AGN_ZIP_CD
JOIN ASRD_CANDIDATES AC ON S.ZIP_CD = AC.ZIP
WHERE --AAE.AGN_ZIP_CD >= '63026'
--AND 
@c.STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::Parse('Point(' + CAST(longitude AS VARCHAR)  + ' ' + CAST(latitude AS VARCHAR) + ')')) >= @dMin 
AND AC.ADDED_DT >= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
```

Comment: This is not a solution, but it may point you in the right direction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821999/how-to-get-all-other-postcodes-or-latitude-longitude-from-table-near-by-give?rq=1

Comment: Slight detour....be careful when casting as varchar. You didn't specify the length and it will use the default. Do you know what the default is? Do you know the length can change based on usage? Do you know it could change in the next release? Always specify varchar length and avoid some potential serious problems with your code.

Answer (score 2):

I use a UDF due the the complexity of the calculation.

Here you pass the base Lat/Lng along with the Lat/Lng to be tested

**To Be Clear:** The distance is "as the crow flies" and NOT driving distance.

For example:

```
Declare @BaseZip  varchar(10) = '02806'
Declare @Within   int         = 20

Select Distinct
       BaseZip = A.ZipCode
      ,B.ZipCode
      ,B.CityName
      ,B.StateCode
      ,Miles = [dbo].[udf-Geo-Calc-Miles] (A.Lat,A.Lng,B.Lat,B.Lng)
 From (Select Distinct ZipCode,Lat,Lng From [dbo].[ZipCodes] where ZipCode=@BaseZip) A
 Join [dbo].[ZipCodes] B
   on [dbo].[udf-Geo-Calc-Miles] (A.Lat,A.Lng,B.Lat,B.Lng) <= @Within
 Order By 5
```

Returns

[image]

The UDF if interested

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[udf-geo-Calc-Miles] (@Lat1 float,@Lng1 float,@Lat2 Float,@Lng2 float)  
Returns Float as  
Begin 
   Declare @Miles Float = (Sin(Radians(@Lat1)) * Sin(Radians(@Lat2))) + (Cos(Radians(@Lat1)) * Cos(Radians(@Lat2)) * Cos(Radians(@Lng2) - Radians(@Lng1)))
   Return Case When @Miles is null then 0 else abs((3958.75 * Atan(Sqrt(1 - power(@Miles, 2)) / @Miles))) end
End
```

> **EDIT**

You may notice some repeating/identical miles.  As you may know, Cities may have alternate names, for example Brown University and Brown Station is in Providence, RI but organization may also have their own zip code.

Comment: swish! That's very kewl, nice job!

Comment: @StelioK Thanks for the grin :)