# Ride Sharing App - finding surrounding origins and destinations

Tags: sql-server, api, coldfusion, latitude-longitude, geography

I looked at several other SO questions that seem somewhat related, but not quite what i need (or i'm just not smart enough to connect the dots).

Working on an app for a client.  Their database holds the origin and destination of people that are traveling, limited (i believe) to just places in US and Canada, and a date when the trip will take place.  The records are updated regularly.  Call these "trips."

Users come to the site, and enter an origin and destination city, and a radius for each, indicating how far away from their desired origin/destination cities they are willing to travel in order to make their trip.

The job of the app is to find any/all trips that are already in the database, that are closest to the origin and destination that the user needs to travel.

My original thought was to find all origin cities in the database that are within the radius of the user's desired origin, then use that recordset to search the destination cities in the database for any/all cities within the radius of the user's desired destination.

I also need a decent (preferably free... low budget project here) API that can help look up the city geographic location and perform the actual radius calculation... I think.

Is what I'm looking to do even close to the best options? It looks like the hardest part will be finding all the existing cities in the database that are within the radius of the user's desired cities - which is a bit of a twist on a more simple query of just "find all cities in the radius of X city".

So, this is KINDA like an Uber situation, except the Uber driver is deciding what the trip parameters are, and the user just needs to know which Uber drivers are going from/to the places nearest those of the user (on the specified date, to boot).

Right now, users are just looking things up at a state level - BC to NY, and reading down rows of data looking at rides to find the ones that seem closest to what they need.

Thanks in advance, for any clever insights you smart folks might have!

Comment: And in thinking about this further, i think it would be acceptable to simply convert cities to zip codes, rather than trying to do actual geographic calculations. Finding all zipcodes within a distance of a specified zip code is fairly easy.  Just need an API that can handle both US and Canadian postal codes....

Comment: Just for your consideration, the radius of N miles can be your initial filter, but drive time/distance should be the second filter.  For example, as the crow-flies, I am only 2 miles from Warwick, however due to the Narragansett Bay, it is almost 25 miles.  The Google APIs would be a great place to start.  Depending on volume, you may need to pay for the extended service agreement ... the cost is nominal

Comment: Wow John, thanks for the fast reply! Thanks for the advice.  I am looking now for information on the cost for Google's API for such a feature, but if you have a link that'd be cool.  =)

Comment: A good place to start  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Comment: It looks like the google api doesn't offer a specific feature to find all zips within a radius of a specified zip.

Comment: No, but you can download the entire database.  One free download is http://federalgovernmentzipcodes.us/   https://www.zipcodeapi.com/   zipcodedownload.com (I use this one .. updated quarterly ... yes they do change.  See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41268902/sql-query-that-gets-all-the-zip-codes-address-within-a-20-mile-radius-of-a-giv/41269282#41269282

Comment: Kinda got myself turned around a bit on this... since our existing trips (updated every 15 minutes) do not contain lat/long or zip code data, every time the data is received, I'll need to look up and store the zip codes for each row.  then when a user enters a city (or zip, i suppose), i need a list of all zipcodes within the radius of that city's zip code, and search the trip data on that criteria.  I'm kinda lost at this point... if I just download a zipcode/city/geo database, would i need google at all?

Comment: In this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41268902/sql-query-that-gets-all-the-zip-codes-address-within-a-20-mile-radius-of-a-giv/41269282#41269282 Let's assume the driver's lat/lng is supplied by his phone (that would be lat1/lng1) then you run the query supplied (the udf can be embedded in the query).  This will give you all zip codes with in N miles

Comment: See answer just posted

Comment: So to summarize the app logic,

1. client obtains US/Can zip/geo database-cities, containing their zip & lat/long data;
2. User provides origin city and/or zip, and destination city and/or zip, and a radius;
3. Look up user's origin and destination cities, get lat/long for each;
4. Use the UDF to find all zip codes around origin, and all zip codes around destination, within the user's radius;
5. Query Trips, where the trip has a zip code in the list of origin zip codes in the radius, and the trip has a zip code in the list of destination zip codes in the radius;

Comment: That's a good start.

Comment: And if the client were to purchase that company's distance wizard:  https://zipcodedownload.com/Products/Product/DistanceWizard/Standard/Overview/ that might expedite the whole thing too, i guess. no need for any APIs anywhere, since the API would be provided, even in ColdFusion... and it looks like the pro version has some good optimizations.

Comment: One last thought... You'll need a cool name like UBER or LYFT

Comment: BAHAHAHA yeah.  Probably something like "hitchhyke" or "pimpYourRyde"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @DriverLat float = 41.744068    
Declare @DriverLng float = -71.315024
Declare @Within   int         = 20


Select *
 From (
        Select Distinct
               A.ZipCode
              ,A.CityName
              ,A.StateCode
              ,Miles = [dbo].[udf-Geo-Calc-Miles] (@DriverLat,@DriverLng,A.Lat,A.Lng)
         From  [dbo].[ZipCodes] A
         Where CityType = 'D'
           and ZipType  = 'S'
      ) A
 Where Miles <= @Within
 Order By Miles
```

Returns

[image]

The UDF

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[udf-geo-Calc-Miles] (@Lat1 float,@Lng1 float,@Lat2 Float,@Lng2 float)  
Returns Float as  
Begin 
   Declare @Miles Float = (Sin(Radians(@Lat1)) * Sin(Radians(@Lat2))) + (Cos(Radians(@Lat1)) * Cos(Radians(@Lat2)) * Cos(Radians(@Lng2) - Radians(@Lng1)))
   Return Case When @Miles is null then 0 else abs((3958.75 * Atan(Sqrt(1 - power(@Miles, 2)) / @Miles))) end
End
```